React : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
I am new to react just started few days ago, everything was working fine before and it still works fine in local. Only when I deploy the project on production react build file throws this error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

This this the piece of build file, it's last line. I am not sure why export is here.
("root")).render(p.jsx(v.StrictMode,{children:p.jsx(EI,{})}))});export default CI();

This is my vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})

This is Package.json
{
  "name": "myaccount-page",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "cropperjs": "^1.6.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.4",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-cropper": "^2.3.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-easy-crop": "^5.0.8",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.7",
    "vite": "^5.3.4"
  }
}

I don't know what I am doing wrong,
But this happened after using react-cropper and react-color packages.
Please help, I am completely new member in react family.
UPDATE
I don't know yet what was the issue but as i mentioned this happened after using react-color, so i removed react-color and all worked.
Thank you to all who read and didn't say anything and who didn't understand and negative marked it. Thanks again.

Hard to say without more information. It might be using a node version that is too low, it should be at least node v18 or v20

@4cyc it's node v20. What information do you need? I have spent few hours i can't find the issue. Please help

Probaly because of the issue was related to the react-color package. let try re-install node_module:
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install

or try config defineConfig:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [react()],
 build: {
    target: 'esnext'
 }
})


Thanks, I have removed the package and using react-colorfull package now. But looks like the issue was in node itself. later i faced same issue with new package and just restarted computer and all worked. it still happens sometime and i restart computer all works, clearing cache don;t help.
